# How to delete all that match

Tags: c

Right now this function is deleting the last name given by the user from a list, but I need it to delete all the names that match the name given by the user, not just the first occurrence of the user input, and need to free up allocated memory of the names that got deleted. How can I do this?

```
int deleteR(char**Fname,char **Lname,float *score,int count)
      {
          int i=0,j=0;
          char *Lastname;
          printf("\n Enter the Last Name of the Student you would like to delete from the records.  ");
          Lastname = (char *)malloc(15 * sizeof(char));

          printf("\nLast Name: ");
          scanf("%s",Lastname);

           int counter = count;

          for(i=0;i<count-1;i++)
          {
             if(strcmp(Lname[i],Lastname)==0)
             {
                 for(j=i;j<count;j++)
                 {
                     Lname[j]=Lname[j+1];
                     Fname[j]=Fname[j+1];
                     score[j]=score[j+1];
                }

                counter--;

             }

          }
             count=counter;
             return count;
          }
```

Comment: After you delete a name, the indexes of the following entries shift down. But then you increment `i`, so you skip the element that moved into the old `i` place.

Comment: This is a common error when deleting from an array while you iterate through it.

Comment: @Barmar is it possible for you to give me more of a hint on how to fix that? srry I'm not good at thinking in code .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your loop on *j* remove entries because you do not change *count*  later in a loop on *i* you will access values already checked and may freed because removed

You also have a memory leak because you allocate memory for *Lastname* but you never free it, and in fact there is no reason to not have *Lastname* as an array in the stack. Also your *scanf* can write out of *Lastname* without limit in size.

You do not need to have two embedded loops as you do, only one is enough to move entries managing an index to write and an other to read :

```
int deleteR(char**Fname, char **Lname, float *score, int count)
{
  char lastname[16];

  printf("\nEnter the Last Name of the Student you would like to delete from the records: ");
  if (scanf("%15s", lastname) == 1) {
    int i;

    /* that first loop to search if the lastname is present */
    for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
      if (!strcmp(Lname[i], lastname)) {
        /* at least present one time, update lists */
        int futureCount = count - 1;
        int j;

        /* it seems you want to free removed resources */
        free(Lname[i]);
        free(Fname[i]);

        /* that loop to move useful elements */
        for (j = i + 1; j < count; ++j) {
          if (strcmp(Lname[j], lastname)) {
            /* still usefull */
            Lname[i] = Lname[j];
            Fname[i] = Fname[j];
            score[i] = score[j];
            i += 1;
          }
          else {
            /* useless */
            /* it seems you want to free removed resources */
            free(Lname[j]);
            free(Fname[j]);
            futureCount -= 1;
          }
        }

        return futureCount;
      }
    }
  }
  else
    puts("EOF");

  return count;
}
```

Using that *main* function to check :

```
int main()
{
  char * fname[5];
  char * lname[5];
  float score[5];
  int count, i;

  fname[0] = strdup("Wolfgang Amadeus");
  lname[0] = strdup("Mozart");
  score[0] = 0;

  fname[1] = strdup("Johann Sebastian");
  lname[1] = strdup("Bach");
  score[1] = 1;

  fname[2] = strdup("Leopold");
  lname[2] = strdup("Mozart");
  score[2] = 2;

  fname[3] = strdup("Johann Christian");
  lname[3] = strdup("Bach");
  score[3] = 3;

  fname[4] = strdup("Ludwig van");
  lname[4] = strdup("Beethoven");
  score[4] = 4;

  count = deleteR(fname, lname, score, 5);

  printf("new lists:\n");
  for (i = 0; i != count; ++i)
    printf("%s %s : %g\n", fname[i], lname[i], score[i]);

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and executions :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall d.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out

Enter the Last Name of the Student you would like to delete from the records: Chopin
new lists:
Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart : 0
Johann Sebastian Bach : 1
Leopold Mozart : 2
Johann Christian Bach : 3
Ludwig van Beethoven : 4
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out

Enter the Last Name of the Student you would like to delete from the records: Mozart
new lists:
Johann Sebastian Bach : 1
Johann Christian Bach : 3
Ludwig van Beethoven : 4
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Comment: `free(Lname[i])` -- this is going to blow. because the caller most likely has allocated the memory in a `char LName[10][100]` fashion. I'd rather return the number of entries and let the caller deal with the allocations/deallocations.

Comment: @lenik visibly this is not the case because (1) in the question tte OP writes "*allocated memory of the names that got deleted*", (2) without freeing resources it is not a problem to access several times at some entries as this is the case in the OP definition and (3) the OP never put the question in S.O. Note also I put a comment to clearly indicate that :-)

Comment: @bruno Thank you so much!

Comment: @chanu you welcome, hoping you understand what was wrong in your code and why my code works, you have a great chance to need something similar of that exercise in the future. Happy coding